# FPDF library not showing special characters like '✓'

Tags: fpdf, fpdi

Hey I try to write special characters like '✓' to FPDF and it's not work. Only normal string work.
I have checkbox on the pdf and i try to fill the checkbox with '✓'.

I try it like this:

```
$value = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1255', html_entity_decode('✓')); 
$pdf->Write(0, $value);
```

But when i go to the pdf and the string broken and not the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This character is not included in `windows-1255`. You may use "ZapfDingbats" and use `chr(51)` or `chr(52)`.

```
$pdf->SetFont('ZapfDingbats', '', 12);
$pdf->Write(0, chr(51));
```

See [here](http://fpdf.org/en/script/fontdump.pdf) for a font dump of all standard fonts.